# Tor browser doesnt launch on tail

Tags: tails

Got live Tail installed on my usb device,run it and when  all thing get started (tor conection etc etc) when i try to run tor browser, nothing !

Comment: What method are you using to start the Tor browser?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors or warnings when starting the system? (As reported in [this thread](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4930/tails-tor-not-starting), for example.)